# Rpi not connecting to wifi

Tags: raspbian, wifi

i, I have screwed up my Rpi by installing some unsupported deb packages and had to do everything from scratch. The biggest problem is with the wifi. First time I got it to work somehow but it took a while and now I don't remember how to get it to work. I got RTL8188cus dongle.

my /etc/network/interface/ looks like this:

```
    auto lo     
    iface lo inet loopback              
    auto eth0         
    allow-hotplug eth0         
    iface eth0 inet manual         
    auto wlan0         
    allow-hotplug wlan0         
    iface wlan0 inet manual         
    wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf         
    iface default inet dhcp         
    auto wlan1         
    allow-hotplug wlan1         
    iface wlan1 inet manual
```

and wpa_supplicant.conf  looks like this:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev     
update_config=1     network={
ssid="¯\_(ツ)_/¯"     
psk="pass"     
proto=RSN     
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP     
auth_alg=OPEN     }
```

when I use iwlist scan my network show up as "\xC2\xAF_(\xE3\x83\x84)_/\xC2\xAF" I tried to use it as ssid in wpa_supplicant.conf  but it doesn't change anything. I also tried changing the ssid of the network to plain text such as "R". I ran out of ideas here. 
What do you guys think?

Comment: Can you try Wifi Config from with X?  It's a much easier setup experience...

Comment: What version are you running? What do you mean by "everything from scratch"?

Comment: I've used rtl8188 cus wifi adapters in the past and it just works out of the box. I think something is wrong in your configuration. Like Brian suggested, using GUI for wifi configuration is the simplest way.

Comment: try changing wpa-roam to wpa-conf in /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: Do you have a wifi dongle?
Because raspberry pi doesn't have built in wifi!